# Clojure - Integer range validation with Prismatic

Tags: clojure

Using [`Prismatic/Schema`](https://github.com/Prismatic/schema), I can validate Integers easily with `s/Int`.

How can I make sure that the integer is in a given range ((0 - 10000) in my case) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use predicate:

```
(defn between
  [min max]
  (s/pred #(<= min % max) (list 'between min max)))

(s/check (between 1 100) 4);; => nil
(s/check (between 1 100) -4);; => (not ((between 1 100) -4))
```